# Signal Refresh issue on some clients in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have developed an application in ASP .NET MVC using SignalR Everything is perfect the only issue I am facing is when I perform CRUD some of the clients are updated using SignalR and some of them are not updated.
Please help me to figure out this issue

```
public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
      app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      app.MapSignalR();
   }
}

public class SettingHub : Hub
{
   public static void BroadcastData()
   {
      IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SettingHub>();
      context.Clients.All.updatedData();
   }
}
$(function () {
  var notificationFromHub = $.connection.settingHub;

  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
     FetchSettings();
  });

  notificationFromHub.client.updatedData = function () {
     FetchSettings();
     };
  });
```

Comment: if some of them are updated which means signalR working properly. the issue is that  the list of connected clients are not persist. you need to check why some client are disconnected.

Comment: This answer provides absolutely no way to debug your current situation. What do you mean "Some of them are not updated". Check your chrome network tab. Are the requests turning 200 responses? Add `console.writeline`s and see if things are being called correctly.

Comment: As far as it is probably a client issue I would start with setting some breakpoints in js and find the difference between working and not working clients.

Comment: some of the clients are updated by signalr automatically and which client does not update I just refresh that page the updated data will be shown

Comment: @user2809176 I put the breakpoints, the client(browser) automatically fetches the data from the server when some changes happen on the server and the client(browser) which is updated is not automatically fetch data from the server when something changes on server

Comment: @Vishalmodi how do i check the connected persistent clients and is there any code i have to write in my program

Comment: you need to handle onconnected event, using client browser, so whenever clicnet is disconnected, you hub class will be call where you will get when and why connection lost.

Comment: @FrankerZ yes response coming from the server is 200, the only issue is those clients who are not updating they are not calling automatically when something happens on the server.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside `notificationFromHub.client.updatedData` for not updating clients it is not firing?

Comment: http://vvms.azurewebsites.net/ please check this site

Answer (score 0):

I just shuffle the code and it works

```
public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
      app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      app.MapSignalR();
   }
}

public class SettingHub : Hub
{
   public static void BroadcastData()
   {
      IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SettingHub>();
      context.Clients.All.updatedData();
   }
}
$(function () {
  var notificationFromHub = $.connection.settingHub;

  notificationFromHub.client.updatedData = function () {
     FetchSettings();
     };
  });
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
     FetchSettings();
  });
```